# I want to edit gridview cells using DataRowView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to update my gridview doing the the following. However the values are not changing in the gridview. I'm not sure what I'm not doing.

```
protected void grvAgents_OnRowDataBound (object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (hours)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            rowView["TotalLoginTime"] = ConvertToHours (rowView["TotalLoginTime"].ToString (), 2);
            rowView["TotalActive"] = ConvertToHours(rowView["TotalActive"].ToString(), 2);
            rowView["TotalWTime"] = ConvertToHours(rowView["TotalWTime"].ToString(), 2);
            rowView["TotalIdle"] = ConvertToHours(rowView["TotalIdle"].ToString(), 2);
            rowView.EndEdit();
            rowView.Row.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Are the changes affected in the database ?

Comment: I actually found another one to do this by assigning a function to bound fields within the gridview itelf, e.g. Text='<%#ConvertToHours(Eval("TotalActiveTime").ToString()). But thanks.